# Kentico Custom Form control type:

Tags: kentico

I want to give an user input with special characters to search for it.I am using text box as form control type and it didn't work for "xxx & xxxx". So looking for suggestions if it is with Form control type or something else.If yes, please do let me know to fix it.  Have a look at this picture [FieldContorl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbQYB.png). Assume Field or searchName is formated as "xxx & xxxx". In order to find results for searchname what do you suggest for Documentname

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to do here.  Do you want this user input with a smart search index?  For example, so that you can search for documents that contain *TermA* **and** *TermB*, or are you trying to achieve something else?

Comment: @mnield yes i am trying search for documents that  are formated as "TermA & TermB".

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using web service and AJAX calls.

 Restrict the AJAX call firing based on your input length like 3 or 4 characters minimum.